# Rsyslog default action name not sequential?

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I would like to ask question about rsyslog.

I am using *rsyslog v7* and gathering stats using *impstats module*.
According to [document](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/actions.html), default naming of action queue is **sequential** based on occurrence of action inside rsyslog configuration.

> name word
>
> This names the action. The name is used for statistics gathering and
>   documentation. If no name is given, one is dynamically generated based
>   on the occurence of this action inside the rsyslog configuration.
>   Actions are sequentially numbered from 1 to n.

However, after the definition of *dynFile* the action number jumps from 3 to 5

```
Sep 10 15:42:54 B rsyslogd-pstats: dynafile cache RemoteHost: requests=1427979 level0=871360 missed=57000 evicted=56990 maxused=10 
Sep 10 15:42:54 B rsyslogd-pstats: action 1: processed=1427979 failed=0 
Sep 10 15:42:54 B rsyslogd-pstats: dynafile cache Dashboard: requests=7018 level0=5941 missed=4 evicted=0 maxused=4 
Sep 10 15:42:54 B rsyslogd-pstats: action 2: processed=7018 failed=0 
Sep 10 15:42:54 B rsyslogd-pstats: action 3: processed=85295 failed=0 
Sep 10 15:42:54 B rsyslogd-pstats: action 5: processed=82487 failed=0 
Sep 10 15:42:54 B rsyslogd-pstats: action 7: processed=609 failed=0 
Sep 10 15:42:54 B rsyslogd-pstats: action 9: processed=832 failed=0
```

After *action 3* , I use the forwarding rule using **legacy format**

```
:hostname, isequal, "BC" @BF
& ~
```

Is this numbering result natural behavior?